# Generate combinations of 0s and 1s

Tags: vba, excel

I have two rows of cells: A1, B1, C1 and A2, B2, C2. In each of these 2 rows there can only be a single 1, with the two other cells set as 0. Here is one example occurrence:

```
    A   B   C
  +---+---+---+
1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
  +---+---+---+
2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
  +---+---+---+
```

I'm trying to iterate over all 9 possible combinations: 3 possibilities for the first row times 3 possibilities for the second. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Please remember we do not know anything about what you are trying to do.  Always err on the side of providing too much information.  It is hard to understand what you want.  It would help if you include what you have tried, it will give us some base on which to understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Function delta(i As Long, n As Long) As Variant
    'returns an array of length n
    'consisting of all 0 with one 1
    'at index i
    Dim A As Variant
    ReDim A(1 To n) As Long
    A(i) = 1
    delta = A
End Function

Sub IterateOver()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To 3
        Range("A1:C1").Value = delta(i, 3)
        For j = 1 To 3
            Range("A2:C2").Value = delta(j, 3)
            'stub for real code:
            MsgBox "Continue?", vbQuestion, "Test"
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate all 8 combinations of `0` and `1` for 3 columns

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 2^3
    Range("A" & i) = (i-1) % 2
    Range("B" & i) = Int((Range("A" & i))/2) % 2
    Range("C" & i) = Int((Range("B" & i))/2) % 2
Next i
```

Try to extend it yourself

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what OP is asking for -- although just what they are looking for is not at all clear.

Comment: Dude, why the vote down, every edit the OP changes his question

Comment: I didn't downvote you. If anyone deserves a downvote it is OP (though I didn't downvote them either since I am trying to be more gentle with new users). I am voting to close their question as "unclear".